# My jar file runs but nothing comes up

Tags: java

I have been searching the internet, but I can't find a solution for this. My program works fine in Eclipse, but I have to make the program into a `.jar` file so the user can just click on the `.jar` file and the GUI will run.

When I click on the `.jar` file that I exported, nothing happens. There is just the main class of the program and if I click run in Eclipse, the GUI will come up.

What do I need to add in here so the GUI will stay and not disappear straight away? I tried to put a `JOptionPane` in there and it works, the box will come out but the GUI will not still.

```
package dijkstra;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RunGUI {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FlightSchedulerGUI.setWindowsLookAndFeel();
        try {
            Map<Integer, Airport> airports = FileProcess.loadtegMap();
            FlightSchedulerGUI GUI = new FlightSchedulerGUI(airports);
            GUI.randomizeRoute();
            GUI.findBestRoute();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(GUI);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setTitle("Flight Scheduler");
            frame.setSize(600,400);
            frame.setVisible(true);



        } catch(Throwable t ){
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.err.flush();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Open a command prompt, and type `java -jar theJarFile.jar`. See what you get.Tell us if you're stuck.

Comment: its said failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from RunGUI.jar

Comment: I've never used Eclipse, but in NetBeans you need to define the "entry point" of the program (a class that has a `public static void main` method)

Comment: yes i have set this class to the entry point, and its the only class that contains a main method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have added the Main-Class attribute to the MANIFEST file of your jar file.

Example:

Main-Class: dijkstra.RunGUI

The file must be called MANIFEST.MF and must be placed to META-INF folder, within your jar file.

[More info](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-35.htm)

Comment: hi there i have added the MANIFEST.MF, but now it give me another error saying: java.io.FileNotFoundException: airport.txt(???????).....but the file is inside the .jar file n the program works fine in eclipse, do u know whats the problem of this??

Comment: Maybe you need to place the file in the same directory in which the jar file is

Comment: @mon999: that'll be a different question, but essentially you would have to read your file using something like [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

Comment: this is how im reading the file in another class 
 Scanner inAirports = new Scanner(new File("airports.txt"));